# An aspiring electriconic engineering hobbyist -- How should I go about this?

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, programming, arduino-uno, learning

I'm a full-time maintenance technician with no University education (though I did get college credit in highschool for physics and statistics 9 years ago), and I have plenty of interests I want to indulge in, feeling like I've already wasted so much of my time in life. I'm just searching for some professional guidance on sources and ways I can get some detailed learning in my free time. I'm currently working on 18 seperate projects from a pretty cool site called CreationCrate. And while I will say it does seem to be a nice and simple start, I'm looking to learn a lot more than what they give. These projects, in their "finalized" state, consist of an UNO R3 microcontroller wired to a breadboard consisting of all the required components. But I don't like that. After a bit of searching, I've decided I would like to actually finalize each of these projects more by designing PCBs for them and possibly fully integrating microcontroller chips in them instead of using the original microcontroller module.

However, I don't know how these work exactly or how I should go about making these decisions. I don't know anything yet about PCB design or integrating these chips. I don't know how many things I could get wrong if I just ordered any microcontroller chip and started learning PCB design and just went for it. I just have these visions of how I want to do much more than these CreationCrate projects leave me. Do I start learning about the creation of arduinos first? About designing PCBs? Where are good places and/or sources for this? I would like to get some advice, from you, on what and where I should start learning to be able to make these decisions myself on how I want to finalize these projects, and eventually, maybe even designing and implementing my own embedded systems and unique and personal projects.

Comment: Quite apart from *The Art of Electronics* (an excellent book I have used in various editions since the early 80s), I suggest Op Amps for everyone. This is an earlier edition but is still an excellent resource. https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf

Comment: This question and its answers are subjective, which is off-topic. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 4):

Recommending "The Art Of Electronics" is a bit opinion based and my opinion is it's an excellent book and you should get it.

Why you need an understanding of the analog basics is simple: without it, nothing works properly.

I mean yes you can do awesome stuff with microcontrollers without having any idea what an impedance is, but... if you don't take into account power supply, ESD basics, input protection, decoupling, etc... then the awesome microcontroller is going to crash and reboot unexpectedly a lot more than it should, which is never. And if you try to debug it without knowing the basics, it'll take more time than reading the book ;)

You don't need to spend a lot of time on intricate stuff like low noise design unless you need it, but simple stuff like "is my MOSFET going to stay cool while switching the load or is it going to puff smoke", then yeah: gate drive voltage, RdsON, dissipated power, thermal resistance, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's a pretty good question, there are lots of possible answers, and I hope nobody takes exception as it could be seen as "opinion based".

My suggestion would be to start by investing in some basic test gear - a minimum would be:

1. a bench DC PSU (adjustable, current limited)
2. a multimeter
3. a scope

All in all that would be a couple hundred new, but you might find very decent quality older equipment for less on your local second hand market. (Old analogue scopes are great learning tools and can be picked up for a song.)

I also recommend Horowitz and Hill's book "The Art Of Electronics" (which is also an investment, but you can get 2nd edition probably for a bit less) which I think is one of the best combinations of theory and practical advice in a single volume that you can find.

You can also get into designing PCB's and programming arduinos, but those won't teach you much the fundamentals of electronic circuits, and there is no substitute for that. If you get some simple test gear and then start actually building and testing real circuits, I think that will serve you best in the long term.

Comment: Indeed. I just looked for a site I felt I could get some decent leads. After posting the question, I saw about how this site is actually used. No opinion based questions and no discussion. Sad. But I will be asking in multiple places. Your recommendation of that book is exactly the kind of thing I am looking for.  I do have some equipment, like a multimeter, and in these projects I have been putting some circuits together and doing some programming and creating some of my own code for these devices I'm building, and I agree there feels like there needs to be some more learning in fundamentals.

Answer (score 2):

I second the opinion about getting Art of Electronics. In addition, you also need something like C for Dummies. Electronics no longer exists separately from the firmware required to drive digital stuff. I'm a professional EE and those two books cover most of what I do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide whether your interests primarily lie in analog or digital electronics; if your focus is in integrating chips with microcontrollers, then the Horowitz and Hill book won't be much use. Conversely, if you want to understand how analog signals are conditioned to go into the microcontroller, then exploring amplifiers, filers etc. would be a good start.

Of course, you can do both, but then you face a bewildering number of choices, which could be off-putting.

I concur with the advice about getting a good power supply, DMM and oscilloscope; the latter is particularly important when trying to understand why circuits don't work as they should; the DMM display is just too simplistic, since it doesn't have a time-component.

I'd also recommend reading the data sheets for every component you use; at first, they will look like gibberish, but gradually they will make sense, and often they contain a small test circuit you can try out for yourself.

With regard to construction, if you are currently using breadboards, I'd seriously consider soldering parts onto matrix board before diving into the complex area of PCB design. It'll help to improve your soldering skills, and is easier to modify if your design is incorrect.

Comment: the 3rd edition of H&H actually has quite a decent section on microcontrollers, along with useful sections on common programming languages, all the usual interface bus types, digital logic, converters, and so on. And I would strongly disagree that you have to start by choosing between analogue and digital electronics; they each rest on the same foundations, without which the OP will soon become unstuck.